# sudo npm cache clean -f messed up sudo permissions

Tags: permissions, 22.04, sudo, npm

`sudo` was initially working when running `sudo npm cache clean -f`, but `sudo` broke after the `npm` command finished running.

```
$ sudo npm cache clean -f
$ sudo ls
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
$ ll /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gameveloster root 232416 Aug  4 06:35 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

Tried to chown the owner back to root, but same error

```
$ sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

```
$ npm --version
8.19.2
$ node --version
v16.18.0
```

Why did this happen, and what should I do to fix this? I cant seem to use `sudo` anymore!

Thank you for any help

Comment: You do anything with python, like change the version?

Comment: @David Nope, did not do anything related to Python

Comment: I would guess that this happened before the command you mentioned? The setuid bit is missing, but afaik you will not be able to set it without `sudo`, unless you have enabled a root password